# How do I code my controller action to receive data from ajax or json call?

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to make an call to my controller using from my asp.net view.  The object parameter of the action is always null.  As this is new to me I thought I must be using the wrong result type.  I’m using

```
Public ActionResult(Object data)
{
    return view();
}
```

After researching I feel like I may need to use something like this:

```
     Public JsonResult(object data)
     {
         Return something();
     }
```

My question is based on my script below, do I need to have specific using statements in my controller?  And should my action be of type ViewResult or JsonResult?

If it is JsonResult that is required, how do I code it to receive data from my ajax  json code below.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(function() {

    var data = [
        ["", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"],
        ["2008", 10, 11, 12, 13],
        ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 13],
        ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 13]
    ];

    var $container = $("#myHandsonTable");

    $container.handsontable({
        data: data,
        startRows: 15,
        startCols: 16,
        rowHeaders: true,
        colHeaders: true,
        useFormula: true,
        minSpareCols: 1,
        minSpareRows: 1,
        contextMenu: true,

        outsideClickDeselects: false,
        removeRowPlugin: true,
        useFormula: true
    });

    $container.handsontable("loadData", data);

    var handsontable = $container.data('handsontable');

    $("#save").click(function() {

        console.log(handsontable.getData());
        console.log(data);
        var myData = handsontable.getData();
        myData = JSON.stringify(myData);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/tableData",
            type: "POST",

            data: handsontable.getData(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });

});
</script>
<button id="save">Click Me</button >
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your getData function I can only assume you are sending it as key value pairs. I believe you need to post data: {data: {}} for it to hit the controller as a the data variable in your controller. The keys in the js object you post map to the parameter names of your controller action.

Comment: I tried doing both data: {"data": handsontable.getData()},
And {data: handsontable.getData()} but the program does not call the controller action.  If I do something like this:

Data:myData it calls the action but with no data sent.